# how to get nested <li> tag value

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the value `"B"`. But coming with value `"A"`. I do not to get the value of "A". How to distinguish?

My HTML structure:

```html
<li>
  <ul>
    <li value="A">
      <ul>
        <li onclick="cick(this)" value="B"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you use jQuery?

Comment: no js 
function(x){
x.getAttribute("value");
}

result B next A coming with i can not do distingush

Comment: List items (`li`) can't have alphabetic values. They need to be numeric. So using JS for this won't work very nicely. Can you use numbers instead of letters (like B = 2, A = 1)?

Comment: `document.querySelector('li[onclick="cick(this)"]').value` this code returns `0` as @NickParsons pointed out, if you use another numeric value, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/re0x2bL1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of a particular `<li>` element when there are more than one in the document, you can distinguish between the element by using unique `id`s or `class`es.

**Option 1: IDs**

```
<li>
   <ul>
      <li id="number1" value="100">
         <ul>
             <li id="number2" onclick="click(this)" value="200"></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

To get the value you would then:

```
function(){
  var el = document.getElementById("number2")
  var value = el.value; // outputs 200
}
```

**Option 2: Classes**

```
<li>
   <ul>
      <li class="number1" value="150">
         <ul>
             <li class="number2" onclick="click(this)" value="300"></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

```
function(){
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("number2")[0]
  var value = el.value; // outputs 300
}
```

Answer (score 1):

List items can't have non-numeric values. For your HTML to be considered valid, you'll need to change your values to numbers. If you do this, you can then easily use javascript to get your values. A HTML structure with valid values may look something like so:

```
<li>
   <ul>
      <li value="1"> <!-- Changed A to 1 -->
         <ul>
             <li onclick="cick(this)" value="2"></li> <!-- Changed B to 2 -->
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

You can use `document.querySelector` and pass in the selector `li[value="1"] > ul > li` (this will select all `li` tags which are a child of a `ul` tag which is a child of a `li` tag with the value of `1`). You can use this generically for a parent list item of value `x` like so:

```
li[value="x"] > ul > li
```

See example below:

```js
const val = document.querySelector('li[value="1"] > ul > li').value;
console.log(val); // 2
```

```html
<li>
  <ul>
    <li value="1">
      <ul>
        <li id="A" onclick="cick(this)" value="2"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```